# How can I log all require()'s in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

`require()`ing all of our code in a Node.js script is taking a while. How can I instrument `require()` to see what's being loaded?

This is difficult because, according to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require),

> `require` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.

So this doesn't work:

```
(function() {
  var slice = [].slice;
  var old = global.require;
  global.require = function() {
    var args = 1 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
    console.log("REQUIRE", args); // Log it!
    return old.apply(null, args);
  };
})();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: just grep your .js files for a /require\(/ pattern? That said I seriously doubt the actual require calls are causing your code to slow down, unless you're using a really deeply nested require chain.

Comment: Can you just use a profiler?

Comment: `require` performs initialization of loaded modules. Apparently initialization of one of the modules takes quite some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override require, it's defined in node/lib/module.js. Same `module` is passed to all files being required. If you change reference in the first file, it'll be reused later.

```
_oldRequire = module.require;
module.require = function(id) {
  var ts = process.hrtime();
  var res = _oldRequire.call(module, id);
  var t = process.hrtime(ts);
  console.log('require(\'%s\') took %s ms', id, t[0]*1000 + t[1]/1e6);
  return res;
};
require('./test123.js');
```

**Update** - version which propagates properly to nested require:

```
var Module = require('module');

_oldRequire = Module.prototype.require

Module.prototype.require = function(id) {
  var ts = process.hrtime()
  var res = _oldRequire.call(this, id);
  var t = process.hrtime(ts)
  console.log('require(\'%s\') took %s ms', id, t[0]*1000 + t[1]/1e6)
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Though, I'm only seeing top-level modules shown, and the override doesn't seem to be propagating globally. Any ideas?

Comment: See update. You might want to add indenting based on module.parent property to see require tree

Comment: Is there a way to know what the full path to the module being required is. When I use this, the new `require` gets used by all downsteam modules, but the `id` doesn't make sense as they can be anywhere internally.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `require.resolve(localPath)` gives you full path to resolved module after all resolution rules are applied